# Print a rectangular frame around array values in C#

Tags: c#

My task is to print words in an array in a rectangular frame. Like this:

```
*********
* Hello *
* World *
* in    *
* a     *
* Frame *
*********
```

I wrote a code witch works just fine, but I'm just curious - how can I do the same just with only one foreach cycle?

```
using System;

namespace RectangleAroundWords
{

class Program
{  
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] words = new[] { "Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame" };
        int length = 0;

        foreach (var item in words)
        {
            if (length < item.Length)
            {
                length = item.Length;
            }            
        }
        String tabs = new string('*', length + 4);

        Console.WriteLine(tabs);
        foreach (var item in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("* " + item.PadRight(length, ' ') + " *");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(tabs);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't (well, you could by using a `for` loop or LINQ - but that is no better than the `foreach`). _Unless you track the max length of the array entries as you **populate** the array. My suggestion would be to use a `List<string>` rather than an array, and keep track of the max length as you add to the list._

Comment: Are you trying to achieve faster performance? Or are you trying just to rewrite the logic just for fun? I ask because you could use lambdas / Func / etc... but behind "doors" there are always loops involved.

Comment: You can use linq to get the max length of your items, and work from there, technically thats still one for loop you wrote, but in practice of course linq is making loops of its own

Comment: Don´t overcomplicate your code for the sake of **optimzation**, in fact optimizing your code will allmost *ever* make it worse.

Comment: Whatever you come up with, you always need to know the length of the longest word before you start the output. You might be able to code something that doesn't look like it's looping twice, but under the covers it probably won't be any different to what you've written.

Comment: `length = words.Max(c => c.Length)`

Comment: You can hide your first foreach under [`Enumerable.Max()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548659(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this snippet you can get the maximum length without the first loop:

```
int length = words.Select(w => w.Length).Max();
```

or shorter:

```
int length = words.Max(w => w.Length);
```

Also I think it would be better to first create the complete output string by using the `StringBuilder` class:

```
string[] words = new[] { "Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame" };
int length = words.Max(w => w.Length);

var sb = new StringBuilder();

String tabs = new string('*', length + 4);

sb.AppendLine(tabs);
foreach (var item in words)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("* {0} *", item.PadRight(length));
    sb.AppendLine();
}
sb.AppendLine(tabs);

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Both Select/Max USES loops underneath

Comment: What is used under the hood does not matter most of the time when writing source code. The source code is an abstraction to be readable by humans and has the nice side effect, that a compiler can also read it and create machine readable instructions from it.

Comment: Of course it matters.... the question is very clear about this subject.

Comment: Thank you for you advice! " int length = words.Select(w => w.Length).Max(); "this is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Although I think [my first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48660799/2029849) is the better approach in readability and best practices, it is possible to do this completley without any loop by using recursion (just to be a nit-picker ;-):

```
public static void Main()
{
    string[] words = new[] { "Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame" };
    var output = Recurse(words);

    String tabs = new string('*', output.Item2 + 4);

    Console.WriteLine(tabs);
    Console.WriteLine(output.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(tabs);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

Tuple<string, int> Recurse(string[] words, int index = 0, int maxLength = 0)
{
    maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, words[index].Length);

    if (index < words.Length - 1)
    {
        var output = Recurse(words, index + 1, maxLength);

        maxLength = output.Item2;

        return Tuple.Create(
            string.Format("* {0} *{1}{2}", words[index].PadRight(maxLength), Environment.NewLine, output.Item1),
            maxLength);
    }

    return Tuple.Create(
        string.Format("* {0} *", words[index].PadRight(maxLength)),
        maxLength);
}
```

Compare and decide yourself...

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create coordinates then calculate the character at each coordinate somehow.

You know the maximum height without looping (`words.Length`) so increment a pointer and take modulo and divisor by this height to give x,y coords. Continue until you don't find any character at the given coordinates.

```
string[] words = new[] { "Hello", "World", "in", "a", "frame" };
int height = words.Length + 4;

int row = 0;
int column = 0;
void Write(char c)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(column, row);
    System.Console.Write(c);
}

int i = 0;
int completedWordCount = 0;
int? lastColumn = null;

do
{
    row = i % height;
    column = i / height;

    if (row == 0 || row == height - 1)
    {
        completedWordCount = 0;
        Write('*');
    }

    if (column == 0 || column == lastColumn)
    {
        Write('*');
    }

    if (row > 1 && row < height - 2 && column > 1)
    {
        string word = words[row - 2];

        if (column - 2 < word.Length)
        {
            Write(word[column - 2]);
        }
        else
        {
            completedWordCount++;
        }

        if (completedWordCount == words.Length && !lastColumn.HasValue)
        {
            lastColumn = column + 2;
        }
    }

    i++;
} while ((!lastColumn.HasValue || column < lastColumn) || row != height - 1);
```

Not exactly a foreach, but only one 'iteration'.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question: "*how can I do the same just with only one foreach cycle?*"

At this point, I only see 2 options:

- If the string list is inserted by the user (BEFORE YOUR CODE and does not comes from a DB table), just read the length of the input and keep it on a MaxLengthTillNow, and then you are ok with it.
- Crappy solution: make the "rectangle" fixed with with 100 :P no matter what you will write inside, will be ok..... but this is probably not the purpose of your problem :)

In conclusion: all the linq/lambdas/func, etc... solutions ARE always using "loops" behind doors..... so, probably there is no answer for your question.